# What is intensity conversion in image processing?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to select the green channel of an image and perform intensity conversion. I have selected the green channel of image. I would like to know how to do intensity conversion. I am currently working in python.

Comment: Normally you take all three channels, RG&B, and apply a formula to them to take a percentage (or other function) of each and call that the `intensity`, which is normally represented in greyscale. Functions may be 33% of each of RG&B, or 30%R + 60%G + 10%B, or otherwise. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be more precise. The "green channel" probably means you have green luma, a correlate of green intensity. They are related via a "transfer function", e.g. as defined as a part of sRGB:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB

This will allow you to flip between luminous intensity of green and luma of green.

Equally likely, you are interested in luminance (CIE Y) or luma. Google for "Gamma FAQ" if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

By selecting the green channel, you're technically already doing an intensity conversion.  This is represented as a grayscale image which denotes how much green is experienced at each pixel in the image.

However, @MarkSetchell is correct where the canonical approach to convert from colour images to intensity is a weighted combination of each colour.  Some people average all of them, other people exaggerate on the green channel more because we perceive that colour more clearly, but the SMPTE Rec. 709 standard is amongst the most popular: `Y' = 0.299 R' + 0.587 G' + 0.114 B'.`

Take a look at these informative links for more details on the conversion:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luma_(video)
- http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/08/24/algorithms-convert-color-grayscale/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale

---

However, since you are using OpenCV, you can simply call [`cv2.cvtColor`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) with the correct flag to convert an image from colour to grayscale:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('...') # Place filename here
im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Alternatively, you can specify 0 as the extra flag to `cv2.imread` to automatically convert any image into grayscale without having the need to call `cv2.cvtColor`:

```
im = cv2.imread('...', 0)
```